# Quiero detectar el tiempo de mi cronometro (JAVA/KOTLIN)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datetime, numberformat

XML:

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.223"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

CODIGO:

```
private val timer : Chronometer by lazy {  findViewById(R.id.timer)}

//EN ESTA LISTA QUIERO COLOCAR EL TIEMPO CON EL CUAL QUIERO TRABAJAR PERO NO SE COMO HACERLO.

val myTyme = listOf(
00:02,00:17,01:00 
) //Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

También probé de separar los números con ';' pero es lo mismo, el problema son los dos puntos (:).
Intenté convertir este formato (02:00) a Int o Long pero no me salió.
Le agregué el tipo **TimeFormat** a la lista pero obtengo los mismos errores.

```
if(timer.text.toString() == myTime.toString() ){
                    timer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple_200)
            }
```

Intente hacer esto pero tampoco funciona

```
        val myTime = "00:08"

        if (timer.text.toString() == myTime) {
            timer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple_200) }
```

Comment: ¿Y el problema cuál sería?...

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu interés! Quiero poner en la lista (myTyme) el tiempo de mi interés, por ejemplo: 00:20 , 00:40, etc; pero no puedo, me sale error, tendría que convertir el formato de la hora, otra opción no se me ocurre. de 02:00 a int por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que kotlin no acepta ese tipo de dato, los datos que están en tu lista deben ser String y mostralos así en todo caso:

```
val myTyme = listOf("00:02","00:17","01:00")
```

Sobre lo otro para que verifiques cuando sea un determinado tiempo, debes hacerlo dentro de su listener **setOnChronometerTickListener** de [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer).

Algo así:

```
timer.setOnChronometerTickListener {chronometer->
            val myTime = "00:03"
            if(chronometer.text.toString() == myTime){
                timer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple_200)
            }
        }
```

Recuerda empezar el conteo del cronómetro, podría ser algo así en OnStart:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    timer.start()
}
```

Comment: No tenia idea de como seguir, por lo que veo me falto conocer en profundidad los metodos del cronometro, ***setOnChronometerTickListener***, tu respuesta me sirvió !Muchas gracias!